# How to compile own project with Tess4J?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

I'm newbie programmer, and i'm not sure how to do this. On their site http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html, it say:

> Tess4J can be built and unit tested using Apache Ant and JUnit. Unzip
>   the source and execute at the command line:
>
> ant test

I do part with building ,ant , but i'm not sure what now, how to test unit with JUnit? Does it is option, or can i just include this previously builded dir (existing project) to Eclipse, and start use Tesseract? Sry for bad english...
Tried to do (this explained, with existing project) with Eclipse but no success...

- And does i need to train him? Like cuting words and numbers, and place them in particular folder, and include then in code?

Comment: `ant test` executes the library's own unit tests, if you just want to use this library in your application as a client you don't need to test and build it. You should just use a compiled .jar artifact, for instance by using Maven and declaring [the appropriate dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j/2.0.0).

Comment: Thanks for advice but, with your opinion there is error by compiling this example from their site http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html, The import net.sourceforge cannot be resolved, *I create pom.xml from this site http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/tess4j/tess4j/2.0.0/tess4j-2.0.0.pom

I found in meanwhile this http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ , but have same error on both, eclipse and nb, can you check this please?

Comment: Do you really need to compile and build Tess4J? Opensource projects are usually just downloaded and included in a runtime. Better visit the download page (https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/).

Comment: I included all jars but still, get error with this example from their site http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html, can't initialized Tesseract, and other staff, it is like i need to include classes, but i tried, without success?